# Seven Cities Of Gold: Does this game have an ending?

Tags: the-seven-cities-of-gold

I am referring especially to the 1993 version for MS-DOS, but I would appreciate answers applicable also to the 1980 versions for Atari, Commodore 64, Amiga and so on.

[image]

I've played many times and never got a victory. The only possible end, for all I know, is when you're killed.

Comment: I don't know about the 1993 Commemorative Edition for the PC, but in the original 1984 version the game effectively ends in 1540. You can continue playing after that but you can't get a better title, essentially your score is locked in at that point. Also dying in the original version doesn't end the game although it's a major setback.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly. This is a screenshot of the/an ending on the Atari:

[image: Ending Screen of Seven Cities of Gold, from http://www.mobygames.com/game/atari-8-bit/seven-cities-of-gold/screenshots/gameShotId,265666/]

However,

> > Accoding to designer Dan Bunten, the only "full" version of the game was made for the Atari. All other ports, including the better selling Commodore version, had to compromise some of the original game aspects to make the port.

(Source: Trivia section on http://www.mobygames.com/game/atari-8-bit/seven-cities-of-gold)

So unless "Returning Home" has been taken out in the DOS version, there exists an ending for the game.

Comment: No, returning home isn't the end of the game. You'd normally return home several times during a game to do things like get new supplies and save the game.

Comment: Woops, I didn't know that :D